# how to display the datavaluefield of selected items in different listbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, listbox

I have 3 listboxes.The listbox fetches two values by `code-datatextfield` and `datavaluefield`. 1st listbox transfers the `datatextfield` items from 1st listbox to 2nd listbox.i want to transfer the `datavaluefield` of selected 1st listbox items to 3rd listbox.

```
if (ListBox3.SelectedIndex >= 0
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ListBox3.Items.Count; i++)
    {
       if (ListBox3.Items[i].Selected)
       {
            if (!arraylist1.Contains(ListBox3.Items[i]))
            {
                arraylist1.Add(ListBox3.Items[i]);
                Session["value"] = ListBox3.Items[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!ListBox2.Items.Contains(((ListItem)arraylist1[i])))
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));

        }
        ListBox3.Items.Remove(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));
    }
    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
else
{

}



SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from IT_1_BOILER_DESK_1_PARAMETERS where paramtext='" + Session["value"] + "'", con);
SqlDataAdapter dataAadpter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAadpter.Fill(ds);
if (ds != null)
{
    ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "param";
    //ListBox3.DataValueField = "param";
    ListBox1.DataBind();
}
```

for listbox 3

```
       protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from IT_1_BOILER_DESK_1_PARAMETERS where pname='" + this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'" ,con);
    SqlDataAdapter dataAadpter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAadpter.Fill(ds);
    if (ds != null)
    {
        ListBox3.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ListBox3.DataTextField = "paramtext";
        ListBox3.DataValueField = "param";
        ListBox3.DataBind();


    }
}
```

But i want to display the datavaluefield of the items that are selected from listbox3 to listbox1

Comment: Please also specify what is the problem you are facing after executing this code?

Comment: datavaluefield of selected items are not displayed in listbox only the datatextfield are displayed.

Comment: You have 3 listboxes. Which list box you are talking about?

Comment: Can you also show usage of ListBox1 in your code? I can only see that its binding to dataset. Also try to assign dataValue field to ListBox1 while binding

Comment: The code which i have written for listbox1 where i want to display the datavaluefield display only a single value and gets replaced if we select other item from listbox.

Comment: just help to fetch the datavaluefields of selected listbox items in another listbox.

Comment: Its not working.How to call the entire listbox items in a session variable.It cannot be done.Is there any other way to fetch datavalue items.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show DataTextField value and DataValueField value from one listbox into 2 different listbox. I suggest you to use a different approach. This will also reduce usage of 2nd database call.

Try following:-

```
if (ListBox3.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ListBox3.Items.Count; i++)
    {
       if (ListBox3.Items[i].Selected)
       {
            if (!arraylist1.Contains(ListBox3.Items[i]))
            {
                arraylist1.Add(ListBox3.Items[i]);
                //Session["value"] = ListBox3.Items[i]; no need of this
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ListBox2.Items.FindByText(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]).Text)==null)
        {
//since you already have text and value field values in arrayList. Use them
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]).Text));

        }
        if (ListBox1.Items.FindByText(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]).Text)==null) 
{
ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem((ListItem)arraylist1[i]).Value));
}

ListBox3.Items.Remove(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));
    }
    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
else
{

}

/* This database call can be removed

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from IT_1_BOILER_DESK_1_PARAMETERS where paramtext='" + Session["value"] + "'", con);
SqlDataAdapter dataAadpter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAadpter.Fill(ds);
if (ds != null)
{
    ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "param";
    //ListBox3.DataValueField = "param";
    ListBox1.DataBind();
}*/
```

Comment: getting error on code for:                                           
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem(arraylist1[i].Text));                  and           ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(arraylist1[i].Value));         
Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: required cast was missing for arrayList[i]. Added now. See edited code